# Nautilus preferences window has no Close/Maximize/Minimize and is partly not displayed (plain grey area)

Tags: nautilus, 14.10, window, window-decoration

I can't apply preferences for Nautilus/Files (Ubuntu 14.10), as there is no way to do so:

[image]

Where do I apply the preferences? I can't close the window without using keyboard shortcuts or killing the process, and there is no buttons to Cancel, Apply or OK. SO! how do I apply my preferences?

Comment: Can you close other windows?

Comment: Usually on Ubuntu most changes are applied the second you make them. So closing the window should be fine. The more interesting question is instead why you don't have the [X+-] buttons in your window's title bar and why the lower half of the window is just plain grey...

Comment: Yes, other windows can be closed without problems, and they have the X+- buttons there too. And no, the changes isn't applied when I check the checkbox, so when I close the window with Alt+F4 or Esc, it is back to what it was. The lower half of the window is grey because I stretched the Preferences window to fit the entire screen, thinking maybe the buttons were hiding out of view. They didn't.

Comment: If you execute a right click with the mouse on the title bar, there's a menu item to close the window?

Comment: I can click the the app-name in the desktop toolbar and close it, or right-click on its title bar and choose to close it, but none of that applies my preferences.